# Spring MVC передача данных в модальное окно bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, spring, mvc

Здравствуйте, есть приложение, на главной странице выводит пользователей из БД, есть кнопка создать, редактировать и удалить. Необходимо было переделать его с использованием bootstrap чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Редактировать" появлялось модальное окно с уже заполненными полями пользователя которого редактируем. Без bootstrap проблем у меня не возникло, я отправлял запрос с id в контроллер, контроллер возвращал мне модель нужного пользователя в отдельный view. А как взаимодействовать с модальным окном - просто не пойму, как передать в модальное окно модель ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC - это бэкенд-фреймворк. Bootstrap - это фронтенд-фреймворк. Друг о друге они ничего не знают и взаимодействовать не могут. Взаимодействовать с модальным окном Bootstrap нужно с помощью JavaScript.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit user</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="firstNameInput">First name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstNameInput" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="lastNameInput">Last name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastNameInput" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="emailInput">E-mail</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailInput" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="user" items="users">
      <tr id="user-${user.id}">
        <td>${user.firstName}</td>
        <td>${user.lastName}</td>
        <td>${user.email}</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-user-id="${user.id}">Edit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>

$("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var userId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('user-id');

  var cols = $('#user-' + userId + ' td');
  var firstName = $(cols[0]).text();
  var lastName = $(cols[1]).text();
  var email = $(cols[2]).text();

  $('#firstNameInput').val(firstName);
  $('#lastNameInput').val(lastName);
  $('#emailInput').val(email);
});

$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  var form = $(this).find('form');
  form[0].reset();
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheDeadOne/jk7yd0z5/1/)

Comment: Спасибо большое, я именно этого и не понимал что "Друг о друге они ничего не знают и взаимодействовать не могут", за код отдельное спасибо.